# Wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) whilst using rails scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just generated some scaffold code using the command `rails generate scaffold Review Title Review:text rating:boolean --skip-stylesheets`. That goes fine, but when I type in `rails server` to start the server, and navigate to `/reviews` I get an error message saying 
`ArgumentError at /reviews`
`wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`

I have not written any code myself, I have only used the scaffolding generator. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your name `Review Title` has a space in it. Try `ReviewTitle`.

**UPDATE**

Try:

```
rails generate scaffold Review title:string review:text rating:boolean --skip-stylesheets
```

Comment: Also, this column name `Review:text` should be lowercase.

Comment: Do I have to "destroy" my previous scaffolding, or can I edit it somehow?

Comment: Was any of it created when you first ran that command? You can either delete what that command made or rename it. I'd suggest deleting it to be safe.

Comment: I juts tried that, but I still get the same error. I tried it with `reviewtitle` instead, but I don't think that is a problem as Review is the name of the model, and title is the first field.

Comment: I get a PG:Error relation "reviews" already exists. How do I delete the previous table in PGAdmin?